# Retrieving random item in array returns 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

I used Math.random() to generate a random number between 1 and however many items are in the array `availableNumbers()`

However, when the document's innerHTML is updated with this, suggestedNumber resolved to undefined,

I tried subtracting 1 from randomNumber but that did not make a difference.

I have checked the W3 documentation and it looks like this is implemented correctly...

How would one best go about retrieving a random item from an array? Is there a better implementation than what I sought to implement?

```
var availableNumbers = ["0", "911"];
function numberSuggestion() {
    var randomNumber = Math.random() * availableNumbers.length -1;
    var suggestedNumber = availableNumbers[randomNumber];
    document.getElementById("suggestion").innerHTML = "How about dialing " + suggestedNumber + "? Don't like this number? Click the button above again!";
}
```

Comment: `console.log(randomNumber);` --- the rule of thumb when you debug: make sure every variable at every point in time has the expected value.

Comment: @zerkms I'm not sure why I would use console.log?

Comment: Because then you'd see why it doesn't work...

Comment: console.log returns doubles between 0 and 1

Comment: @InterLinked do you expect to see doubles between 0 and 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiplying `Math.random()` by an integer will produce a floating point value in the range [0, number). You need to remove the fractional portion to get the integer portion:

```
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * availableNumbers.length);
```

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't solve the problem. I figured since it would resolve to a whole number, OOO wouldn't have mattered.

Comment: Without the -1, this works perfectly! (So I guess I didn't need to subtract 1 after all!)

Comment: Might be cool if the explanation covered the key point about needing an integer result. (I know the code shown does this, but given that the explanation talks about something else the `Math.floor()` part seems less important.)

Comment: @nnnnnn I've fixed the explanation now.

Answer (score -1):

Yo try this function:

```
Array.prototype.choice = function(){
    return this[~~(Math.random()*this.length)];
};

// now you can call it like this :)
console.log( ["0", "911"].choice() );
```

Comment: What was wrong with the original code, and why does this fix it? (I know the code you've shown does work, but an explanation would be helpful for beginners.)

Comment: Its better, reusable, faster, more readable, everything

Comment: Modifying the built-in prototypes is definitely not "reusable", "readable" or "everything". Also `~~` - don't be tricky, there are built-in functions for rounding, that are explicit.